# Is it correct performing GET requests and checks inside a POST handler?

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm designing a ticket booking API. Right now booking a ticket resolves into `POST /users/{id}/tickets` but each `/events/{id}` has a maximum of available tickets. How do I properly design a check?

I've come up with two ways:

1) having an `availibleTickets:` field into the `/events/{id}` that gets checked and possibly updated each time I `POST` a new ticket.

2) having a `maxTickets:` field into `/events/{id}` and check the length of `GET /events/{id}/tickets` array, compare it to `maxTickets`

Anyway I have to perform a `GET` request inside the `POST` handler but it doesn't look right to me, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would you desing a ticketing system for a Web page? The same steps you apply to a Web page also apply to REST as it is just a generalization of the same interaction flow used on the Web.

Usually, on the Web you have a link you can see an event you can order tickets for. On this page you have a link to order tickets for that particular show. Depending on the system you use, you might see a layout of the event venue in the form of buttons or images to click if there is a certain seat order where available seats are marked as green and ones that are already booked as red or whatever color scheme you use. A click on a seat will trigger some reservation logic on the server that returns almost the same page as before but this time with the seat marked as orange to indicate a reservation. Next you click the available seat next to that seat to reserve a further seat. This story continues until you either have enough seats marked as reserved or no available seats are available and you have no options left as to either cancel the reservation, proceed to the order step or unreserve seats you marked as reserved beforehand. Once you are satisfied with your choice, you will find an order or submit button or link where you turn your reservation into a booking. This might involve some further steps like entering your contact and/or billing information. Though this is in principle how I'd design such a system for the Web.

As you might see, this turns out into some kind of state machine where the server tells you all of the options you have available at this current state of the process. This is exactly what Asbjørn Ulsberg mentiones when talking about [affordance and state machines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817). From the blueprint of the venue and the respective seats on that blueprint, which are actually buttons or images you might click, you knew what these widges are for and you somehow know what will happen when you click on one of the seats. This is what *affordance* is all about. By seeing it you know what you can do with it.

The interaction concept outlined above should be taken and translated to REST. As a client you don't need to know the structure of the URI, all you need to know is what seats are available and what happens when you click certain links. This is usually done in REST through link relation names that give the mentioned link some semantical context to the current state of the resource the client just fetched. Such link-relations may seem like a-priori knowledge needed by the client, which is a bit anti-REST, as REST tries to decouple clients from servers to allow the latter one to evolve freely without risking clients to break, though as link-relations should be [standardized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), or should be based on [extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-4.2), such as [dublin-core](http://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dc-html/) or other [microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values). Buidling up on standards will either lead to broad acceptance and support by different clients or on mechanisms to plug-in such knowledge into a client later on. This in general avoids so-called out-of-band information or process flows that force you to lookup up the manual on how to use that system.

The approach outlined above would utilize an own reservation resource that is uniquely created on "entering" the reservation, which is kept till the order ticket step is invoked. This reservation resource keeps track of the reserved seats the user has chosen so far. Whether the system considers reserved seats by other users as taken or not is an implementation detail. It is ok to either use a first-come system or a more polite one that guarantees the reserver his seats until some grace-period has passed and the user didn't order them. This gives you a good impression that such resources can be volatile and just be part of a certain process.

In regards whether to use `GET`, `POST` or other HTTP methods, a Web page that sends you to a reservation page will show you a form containing all of the seats of the venue. As HTML does only support `GET` or `POST`, the latter one is the most appropriate thing. In a REST or HTTP API you might use `PUT` though. A server might already have assigned you a certain, unique "reservation" link that you can just invoke with `PUT`. If the reservation resource does not exist yet, it will be created for you, if it did, the whole content will just be updated. Especially when you dealing with reservations and money flows [you want to use idempotent methods such as `PUT`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=19m40s).

I hope I could give you some ideas on how you might design your reservation system by letting a server teach a client everything it needs to know to proceed through its task.

Answer (score 0):

It's inside the post method (server-side) that you must check if tickets are available before book the event.

you can create a specific route to know how many tickets is available if needed. the client could call it before book an event. Or give the availibleTickets in the get /events/{id}

Imagine 10 client trying to buy the last ticket at the same time, if the security is not in the post method, you'll book 9 imaginary tickets